# Disable bios check

Tags: memory, bios, diagnostic, lenovo-desktop-computer

I have a motherboard from a Lenovo (ST50 i think, Xeon cpu), now in use for a gaming computer.

It has some extra non-lenovo memory installed ("unqualified DIMM"), prompting for "press F2" when starting up.

Is there a way to disable this check in the bios?

[image]

Comment: The first can be solved by disconnecting the faulting fan. The other two can only be fixed by using proper memory

Comment: Proper memory meaning stuff from Lenovo right?

Comment: Memory that Lenovo marked in their manual as being compatible. If that limits to only Lenovo memory, then yes.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct solution but using a Digispark ATtiny85 micro mainboard and the following code, the work-around is to automate an F2 keyboard-press after a suitable delay.

```
  DigiKeyboard.sendKeyStroke(0);
  DigiKeyboard.delay(40000);
  DigiKeyboard.sendKeyStroke(KEY_F2);
```